# One Memcached server for many clients

Tags: java, coldfusion, memcached, spymemcached

We have 2 applications servers (coldfusion / Java) and one memcached.
I want to setup my memcached server/client like that. When server 1 add value for key it should be available also for server 2. And in opposite way also.

Now when i add value for key on server 1 it is not readable or editable on second server.
How to set it up

I use [spymemcached](http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/) as a client library.

Thanks for your help

Comment: First I want to note that both memcached and spymemcached are very reliable and used the thousands of people every day. You are also trying to do something very basic that would be easily caught during testing or either spymemcached or memcached which leads me to believe there is a bug in your code. Can you post the code here? Also if you are using the 2.7 series of spymemcached you can call a getStatus() function from the Future returned to you to see if there was an error in your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was set in a right way, but setting a complex value (Structure or Array) made those key/value pair unavailable for other server.
Now i serialize all my values to JSON and it works fine. Maybe in Memcached version 1.4.5 it is changed, but for version 1.2.6 serializing values is the good way of fixing it.

```xml
<!--- Setting up Memcached Client --->
<!--- Add code in OnApplicationStart in Application.cfc --->
<cfset AU = createObject("java", "net.spy.memcached.AddrUtil").init() />
<cfset Application.MemCacheD  = createObject("java", "net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient").init(AU.getAddresses("127.0.0.1:11211")) />
```

```xml
<!--- Adding values: --->
<cfset memCacheName = "myKey" />
<cfset myValue = StructNew() />
<cfset myValue['var1'] = 'var1 value' />
<cfset Application.MemCacheD.add(memCacheName, 3600, serializeJSON(myValue)) />
```

```xml
<!--- Getting values: --->
<cfset memCacheName = "myKey" />
<cfset MemCachedRet = Application.MemCacheD.get(memCacheName) />
<cfif isDefined('MemCachedRet')>
    <!--- value is available from mamcached --->
<cfelse>
    <!--- get value from db and save to memcached --->
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

A. You aren't using the same key for server 1 and server 2 for the same object.

OR

B. You aren't talking to the same memcached instance for server 1 and server 2

OR

C. You gave such a short lifespan on the object that it expired before the other server could leverage it.

Comment: A - keys are the same  B - there is only one instance of memcache  C - lifespan is 3600 and value is available on first server

Comment: I assert there is a bug somewhere. Assuming you are using stable releases of Memcached and Spymemcached, that doesn't leave a lot of wiggle room. I'd step back and ratchet back down to basics. Make a simple Java class with a main that inserts/retrieves values. Run it on different machines to be sure it works. Use Wireshark to be ABSOLUTELY sure you are passing the same key. Use command line tools available for memcached to check the contents. For example, insert the same value from both servers and run "stats items". Does it have 1 key or 2?

Comment: there is only one ke, for now 'test'. i insert value on one server and on other it is 'undefined'. When i try to overwrite it using ADD on other server i receive status 'OperationStatus success=false: NOT_STORED'.

Comment: Are you positive they are talking to same instance? This just doesn't sound right.

Comment: there is only one instance. i will test it on more servers on monday. i think there is possibility that version of memcached server is too old for current version of spymemcached client. I know that versions of coldfusion are different on servers that can be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that is a rather young Memcached implementation, this might be a bug. You may want to submit it here: http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/issues/list

If you don't think it's a bug, could you post a snippet of the code making calls to Memcached?

Also, keep in mind that memcached should be treated as unreliable and non-persistent storage. You should write your code as though you expect it to go down and possibly even come back with empty results.

Comment: could this be bug in older version of memcached engine ?? couse i use it under windows and only working version i found is 1.2.4 (if i remember well)